# How to change style of validation message in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to change style of mvc validation message.I wrote this jquery for change style of message to `bootstrap alert`.

```
$("form").submit($("form .field-validation-error").wrap("<div class="alert alert-danger"></div>")
.append("<button type="button" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>"));
```

Now When submit form page postback and then this code execute.But I want page validation worked with out post back .Please advice

Answer (score 1):

you can use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) that way you can submit, validate and then postback you form

Comment: I do not want to be post back Page